# What does it mean that Singular Values of two in principle unrelated matrices are really similar?

Tags: matrices, polynomials, svd

I have two matrrices $Q_1$, $Q_2$ of size $5\times8$.
They should not be related to each other, they just describe the 8 coefficients of 5 bivariate polynomials, that should also not be related, apart from the fact that these two sets of polynomials indirectly describe the same data.

When I perform the singular value decomposition of the matrices, it turns out that their singular values are pretty close to each other.

Does that mean something?

I just performed the SVD to play around with the things I had, but this coincidence is a bit strange.

Comment: I suspect "pretty close" really means so close that the difference resulting from rounding in the course of computation, and they're actually identical.

Comment: "these two sets of polynomials indirectly describe the same data"  I think you should be quite specific about the meaning of that statement, because that's probably where the answer will come from.

Comment: If you want to give some details of the exact nature of your data, I am sure someone could see and explain why the SVD does this. The ["cocktail party problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_separation) may be a pertinent example to look at.